# Selecting specific sequence of rows from a matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, subset, sequence

I have a data matrix of order 2000 x 20, and I want to choose a specific order of entire rows from the matrix, for example, 1st,7th, 8th, 14th, 15th, 21th, 22th, is such a sequence of rows until the last 2000th rows.

```
[1, 7, 8, 14, 15, 21, 22, ...]
```

Manually it's very difficult to select such a sequence, is there is an alternative to do the same task in R? are the **for** looping is helpful in solving such a problem.

Comment: It might have been nice to leave the original sequence as well as the updated one, since you already had 2 good answers addressing the question as posed.

Comment: yes, you're right but I did a mistake in the sequence that's why I update it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the updated question data, something like:

```
cumsum(rep(c(1,6), 2000/7))
#  [1]    1    7    8   14   15
#  ...
#[566] 1981 1982 1988 1989 1995
```

Since your pattern is +1/+6 up until 2000, you can `rep`eat the two values `c(1,6)` as many times as `sum(c(1,6))` goes in to 2000, and then take a `cum`ulative `sum`.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your sequence first, using e.g. `sequence`, and then subset using `[]`.

```r
n = 2000 / 7 
s = sequence(nvec = c(1, rep(2,n)), from = c(1, 7*1:n))
# s
# [1]    1    7    8   14   15   21   22   28   29   35   36   42   43   49   50   56   57   63   64   70   71   ...

yourMatrix[s, ]
```

`sequence` creates a sequence of sequences of length `nvec` and of starting point `from`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
mat[sort(c(k <- seq(6, 2000, by = 7), k + 1)),]
```